# Laravel Login and save user details

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authentication

**I want to save the user id,name etc** when a successfull login happens.

This is my code,

```
public function Login(Request $request){
        $result1=json_decode(DB::table('tbl_admin_details')
        ->where('Username',$request->input('username'))
        ->where('Password',base64_encode($request->input('password')))
        ->get(),true);
       if(count($result1)>0){
           return redirect('dashboard');
       }else{
           return redirect('/');
       }
    }
```

when a successfull login happens it will redirect to dashboard, I need to **access the user data in that page**. how its  possible ???

Comment: Have you tried sending data along with the redirect function??
Something like this

return Redirect::route('clients.show, $id')->with( ['data' => $data] );

Comment: Personally, I'd replace the redirect with the use of VIew::make where you can pass in data to be used on the page

Comment: why `base64_encode` and not `bcrypt` ?

Comment: try this return redirect()->route('dashboard, [$result1]);

Comment: I want to use that data in different page. like the php session

Comment: On the 'different page' use `Auth::user()` to get the currently authenticated user

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count($result1)>0) {
  $id= session(['id'=>$result1[0]->id]);
  $name= session(['name'=>$result1[0]->name]);
  return redirect('dashboard');
}
```

Then use `session()->get('id')` and `session()->get('name')`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

in your loginController put method:

```
protected function authenticated( \Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $user) {
     dd(\Auth::user());
}
```

this method fires up when user is successfully logged in
and gives you logged in user information.

feel free to use it as you want

Comment: OP wants to use the data, not log it. This doesn't really answer the question.